# workaround for prohibition on virtual template functions?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

My first foray in to C++ is building an audio synthesis library (EZPlug).

The library is designed to make it easy to set up a graph of interconnected audio generator and processor objects. We can call the EZPlugGenerators

All of the processor units can accept one or more EZPlugGenerators as inputs.

Its important to me that all configuration methods on these EZPlugGenerators are chainable. In other words, the methods used in setting up the synthesis graph should always return a pointer to the parent object. That allows me to use a syntax which very nicely shows the nested nature of the object relationships like this:

```
            mixer.addGenerator(
            a(new Panner())
            ->setVolume(0.1)
            ->setSource(
                a(new TriggererPeriodic())
                ->setFrequency(
                    v(new FixedValue(1), "envTriggerFreq")
                )
                ->setTriggerable(
                    a(new Enveloper())
                    ->setAllTimes(v(0.0001), v(0.05), v(0.0f, "envSustain"), v(0.01))
                    ->setAudioSource(
                        a(new SineWaveMod())
                        ->setFrequency(
                            a(new Adder())
                            ->addGenerator(a(new Adder()))
                            ->addGenerator(v(5000, "sineFreq"))
                            ->addGenerator(
                                a(new Multiplier())
                                ->addVal(v("sineFreq"))
                                ->addVal(
                                    a(new TriggererPeriodic())
                                    ->setFrequency(v("envTriggerFreq"))
                                    ->setTriggerable(
                                        a(new Enveloper())
                                        ->setAllTimes(0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.0001)
                                        ->setAudioSource(v(1, "envAmount"))
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )

            )
        );
```

*The "a" and "v" functions in the above code store and return references to objects and handle retrieving them and destroying them.*

I suspect my approach to C++ looks a little weird, but I'm finding that the language can actually accommodate the way I want to program fairly well.

**Now to my question**

I'd like to create a common superclass for all EZPlugGenerators which can accept inputs to inherit from. This superclass would have a method, "addInput", which would be overridden by each subclass. The problem comes from the fact that I want "addInput" to return a pointer to an instance of the subclass, not the superclass.

This isn't acceptable:

```
EZPlugProcessor* addInput(EZPlugGenerator* generator)
```

because that returns a pointer to an instance of the superclass, not the sublass destroying the chainability that I'm so happy with.

I tried this:

```
template<typename T> virtual T* addInput(EZPlugGenerator* obj){
```

but the compiler tells me I can't create a virtual template function.

I don't HAVE to use inheritance here. I can implement 'addInput' on every single EZPlugGenerator that can take an input. It just seems like gathering all of them under a single parent class will help make it clear that they all have something in common, and will help enforce the fact that `addInput`is the proper way to plug one object in to another.

So, is there a way I can use inheritance to dictate that every member of a group of classes must implement an 'addInput' method, while allowing that method to return a pointer to an instance of the child class?

Comment: Sorry Xeo. I tried to keep it as simple as I could!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Shall I mark you down as one of the "I suspect my approach to C++ looks a little weird" people?

Comment: But they don't have anything in common — all those member functions would be completely different. Also don't use `new` and pointers. Also named parameters > chains.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "named parameters > chains"?

Comment: Something like this: https://ideone.com/eiW38 There is still issue of "too many damn things", but oh well.

Comment: @morgancodes: You can mark me down as one of the "he suspects morgancode's approach to C++ looks a little weird" people

Comment: Ok, Cat Plus Plus, I see what you're saying about named parameters being better than chains. That won't work in the case where I add more than one object as an input to another, as in the calls to "addGenerator" in my example code.

Comment: @morgancodes: Then you pass an array with `{a, b, c}`.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus If you'll forgive my (obvious) ignorance, in that case, how do I tell the receiver how big the array is? Add a null pointer as the last element maybe?

Comment: @morgancodes: It's a language construct, compiler derives the size. See `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Thanks Cat! Another question: my reason for using new is to avoid having to declare variables. This entire approach is designed for very fast prototyping and experimenting with different synthesis networks. I found declaring variables was a hassle and slowing me down. I adopted the convention of creating objects using a(new MyClass()), which returns a pointer as well as storing a pointer for deletion in the destructor. I realize this is weird and generally wrong, but was the nicest way I could think of to avoid having to declare a variable for every object in my graph. Is there a better way?

Comment: @morgancodes: Just create values. `MyClass()` instead of `new MyClass()`.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus If I just use MyClass() instead of new MyClass(), won't the object be destroyed as soon as the function exits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtual functions in C++ can have covariant return types, which means that you can define

```
virtual EZPlugProcessor *addInput(EZPlugGenerator* generator) = 0;
```

in the base class, and then

```
struct MyProcessor : EZPlugProcessor {
    virtual MyProcessor *addinput(EZPlugGenerator* generator) { 
        ...
        return this;
    }
};
```

As long as the caller knows (by the type they're using) that the object is a `MyProcessor`, they can chain `addInput` together with other functions specific to `MyProcessor`.

If your inheritance hierarchy has more levels, then unfortunately you'll sometimes find yourself writing:

```
struct MySpecificProcessor : MyProcessor {
    virtual MySpecificProcessor *addinput(EZPlugGenerator* generator) {
        return static_cast<MySpecificProcessor*>(MyProcessor::addInput(generator));
    }
};
```

because there's no way to specify in `EZPlugProcessor` that the return type of `addInput` is "pointer to the most-derived type of the object". Each derived class has to "activate" the covariance for itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C++ already provides for covariant return types.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual Base* add() = 0 { return <some base ptr>; }
};

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    virtual Child* add() { return <some child ptr>; }
};
```

On the other hand no one will ever be able to read your code so you might want to consider if there's an alternate way to set up the configuration than writing LISP chaining in C++.

Comment: Thanks Mark B. Exactly what I'm looking for. As for the unreadability of my code... it's weird, and for most purposes would be the wrong approach. I agree with you there. But I've come to this style after wrestling with doing this a more "normal" way and finding that that was too slow and, ironically, too hard to read. If you have any ideas for other ways to build and configure object trees in pure C++ using a syntax which allows me to get the gist of the entire structure in a quick scan, please share!

Comment: @morgancodes: one option is to define your own domain-specific language to describe the relations between the components. Perhaps that's an XML/YAML/JSON format, perhaps something you invent from scratch. Then put string literals in your code (or loaded at runtime), parse them, and build the object tree accordingly. Obviously you pay in performance (but the cost is only at setup), and you might have to write more code to support it (especially if you're writing the parser). The benefit is that the definition reads *exactly* as you want it to, no compromises with C++ syntax.

Comment: @SteveJessop That's certainly a viable approach, and is quite common for audio synthesis systems. However, my goal with this project is to keep it all as simple as possible, and to keep it all in C++.